# Yii role based access, administering own posts

Tags: authentication, yii, rbac, role-base-authorization

I googled, read tutorials, blogs and experimented a lot. So I am able to define role based access to controller actions.
Everything works fine.
What I want to ask is. How can I write a rule to display,edit and delete a user's own post?

By default it displays all post. However we can put data provider criteria to display own post. But how can I controll the CRUD for that??
Kindly help me. My code is bellow.

```
 public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions' => array('index', 'view'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions' => array('create', 'update'),
                'expression' => 'Yii::app()->controller->HaveAccess()',
                //'users' => array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions' => array('admin', 'delete'),
                'expression' => 'Yii::app()->controller->HaveAccess()',
            ),
            array('deny', // deny all users
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

**for the post display:**

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Advertisment');
        if (!$this->IsAdmin()) {
            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Advertisment', array(
                        'criteria' => array(
                            'condition' => 'added_by='.$this->userId,
                            'order' => 'id DESC',
                        ),
                        'pagination' => array(
                            'pageSize' => 20,
                        ),
                    ));
        }
        $this->render('index', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: simply add the userid to the those actions just like you are doing for acitonIndex `$this->userId`

Comment: where in the controller are you setting `$this->userId` value?

Answer (score 3):

To restrict update and delete actions to the user's own posts, you will have to check permissions inside the controller action (this is not possible in the controller's `accessRules` afaik, as the id of the post to check permissions for, is not known by the time the `accessRules` are evaluated.)

Example:

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    if($model->added_by === $this->userId){
        // your code here
    }else
        throw new CHttpException(401,'You are not authorized to edit this post.');
}
```

Comment: But somewhere I had seen that we can put something in the accessrul and automatically the listing is also modified for the user

Comment: are you refering to this [Wiki/Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/136/getting-to-understand-hierarchical-rbac-scheme/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use scopes:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#scopes-detail

in your model:

```
public function scopes()
{
return array(
  'own'=>array(
    'condition'=>'userid=' . Yii::app()->user->id,
  ),
);
}
```

and then select your data like this:

```
Post::model()->own()->findAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of doing this is by first modifying the links that activate the actions: *update, delete, view* to send also the `added_by` field along with the post's id (post id is sent by default). Then in your `'expression'` you can check if the `added_by` matches your `userId`. Below is an example for view (assuming you mean view when you say display in your question):

1. accessRule modifications, for this to work make sure you have a value in `$this->userId` before the accessRules is evaluated, that can be done in the [`init()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#init-detail) method :

   ```
   return array(
       array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' actions
           'actions' => array('index'),
           'users' => array('*'),
       ),
       array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
           'actions' => array('create', 'admin'),
           'expression' => 'Yii::app()->controller->HaveAccess()',
           //'users' => array('@'),
       ),
       array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
           'actions' => array('view', 'delete', 'update'),
           'expression' => 'Yii::app()->controller->HaveAccess() && ($_REQUEST["added_by"]=='.$this->userId.")",
       ),
       array('deny', // deny all users
           'users' => array('*'),
       ),
   );
   ```
2. view modification to add `added_by` id to url parameters. Say you have the default generated crud views, namely *index.php, _view.php, _form.php, _view.php, update.php etc*  where *_view.php* has the link to go to the detailview of the post, this is also the itemView of the listview in index.php. Here we make a few changes(_view.php):

   ```
   <div class="view">

      <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
      <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id,'added_by'=>$data->added_by)); ?>
      <br />

      <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('someattribute')); ?>:</b>
      <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->someattribute); ?>
      <br />

      <!-- more attributes-->


   </div>
   ```
3. You'll have to modify the links for delete, update actions to also pass the added_by field.